# entity_metadata_wrapper file load

Tags: theming, nodes, files, entities

I'm trying to load and get the file using entity_metadata_wrapper. this is my code

```
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node',$variables['node']);
$file_field= $wrapper->field_library_file->value();
$variables['file'] = theme('file_link', array('file' => file_load($file_field['fid'])));
```

and `<?php print $file;?>` outputs nothing. I've found this in this [address](http://codekarate.com/blog/theme-file-link-drupal-7) . how can I get set of files that belongs to a node.

thanks.

---

**UPDATE:**

this is the code I use for theme hook suggestion, this code is on top of the the above code.

```
$suggest = "page__node__library";
$variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = $suggest;
```

I created a page and renamed it to `page--node--library.tpl.php` and `<?php print $file;?>` is in this page.

Comment: it prints nothing, is there anything wrong with this code?

Comment: My apologies, I didn't mean to submit that last comment I realised in time you were passing a var through to a template file. `theme('file_link', array('file' => $file_field->value()))` might work

Comment: NOP! it reported error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function value() on a non-object in /home/.../template.php on line ...`

Comment: foreach ($wrapper->field_file_attachments->getIterator() as $attachment) {                                        
$downloads[] = theme('file_link', array('file' => $attachment->value()));
}                                                    see this code it may be helpful.

Comment: @MahipalPurohit it reported this error: `EntityMetadataWrapperException: Unknown data property field_file_attachments. in EntityStructureWrapper->getPropertyInfo()`

Comment: replace field_file_attachments with field_library_file

Comment: @MahipalPurohit iut outputs Array and it is its `var_dump` array(1) { [0]=> NULL }

Comment: this function for multiple file if in your case don't have multiple file then remove foreach and try out.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12531/discussion-between-mahipal-purohit-and-mohammad)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some corrections after, can you put the context of the execution? Like the function where you call this code and where you output $file variable?

```
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node',$variables['node']);
// raw() should give you file object in your case
$file_field= $wrapper->field_library_file->raw();
// theme_file_link 'file' parameters have to be a file object 
$variables['file'] = theme('file_link', array('file' => $file_field ));
```

Docs :

- [theme('file_link') OR theme_file_link](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!file!file.module/function/theme_file_link/7)
- [Raw() Method](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!includes!entity.wrapper.inc/function/EntityMetadataWrapper%3a%3araw/7)

Note :

@clive comment : no need to value() because he have already used that function below, if we follow the source code given... In that case, value() and raw() methods should return the same file object.

```
theme('file_link', array('file' => $file_field))
```

Edit : Can you dump your $file_field variable? You can do it via this snippet

```
drupal_set_message('<pre>'.print_r($file_field, true).'</pre>');
```

Comment: I updated my answer, unfortunately your code didn't work as well :(